# Is there something about the wristwatch?

Tags: plot-explanation, electric-dreams

In the *Electric Dreams* episode entitled *The Father Thing* a particular thing didn't process for me.

Towards the end Greg Kinnear's father-thing character and the boy's mother are worried because their son hasn't come home yet.  He says

> "It's not the first time he's forgotten about the time, is it? Let's give it an hour.
>
> If he doesn't show up, We'll drive around the neighborhood."

While doing so, he looks at his wristwatch and *the view cuts to the detail of the watch face.*

[image]

It really seemed to me that the action was more than incidental or accidental. Upon closer inspection, half of the watch face used Arabic numerals and half used Roman numerals. It also appears to be cracked or damaged, perhaps.

At first I thought it was supposed to convey that the watch was an indication that it was made artificially by beings that didn't understand humans, but then I found out what a [California dial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_dial) is and further convinced myself that any damage was probably caused when it was taken from the real father.

But that still leaves me wondering what the function of this odd cut was. We all know what you see when you look at a wristwatch, and the actual time does not seem to be important.

Perhaps it is linked to something earlier that I didn't notice? Or maybe the person who directed it (Michael Dinner) is known for using such images as flavor?

Comment: I suspect some images would be useful here.

Comment: Agreed: I'll see if I can produce one tonight.